# Python: How to find properties of items in a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of numbers that I have broken into buckets using pandas.cut.

```
agepreg_cuts = pd.cut(df['agepreg'],[0,20,25,30,pd.np.inf], right=False)
```

I then count it and display the count.

```
agepreg_count = (df.groupby(agepreg_cuts).count())
agepreg_count
```

Which gives me much more information than I want:

```
           sest  cmintvw  totalwgt_lb  
agepreg                                
[0, 20)    3182        0         1910  
[20, 25)   4246        0         2962  
[25, 30)   3178        0         2336  
[30, inf)  2635        0         1830
```

Now I want to format it like this:

```
INAPPLICABLE 352
0 to 20 3182
20 to 25 4246
25 to 30 3178
30 to 50 2635
Total 13593
```

Which leads me to a couple of questions.

1. How do I extract the begin/end properties (e.g. 25/30) from the bin `[25,30)`?
2. How do I discover properties in a series so that I do not have to ask SO the previous question?

---

For reference, the data I am using comes from the [nsfg](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg.htm). The free book [thinkstats2](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/) has companion code and data on [github](http://github.com/allendowney/thinkstats2).

From the 'code' directory, you can run the following line to load the dataframe.

```
import nsfg
df = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()
df
```

Comment: Are you mainly asking about access to the breakpoint ends, or about not getting you "much more information than [you] want"?

Comment: And I assume you are asking for more than just the difference btw the values of the if you pass a list to the `pd.cut` (your list had these break points `[0,20,25,30,pd.np.inf]`)? I guess I don't understand the use case; your desired output seems to still have a string with breakpoints as index. Maybe you are just asking about how to produce that label?

Comment: To clarify, the properties of the series are in this case well known because you have the list that defined its preparation. Can you use that?

Comment: I do not know. How would you use it? Anything I can think of would be a bit of a hack.

Comment: It might be a nice enhancement to be able to return a MultiIndex-Categorical with the start/ends. Worth posting as an issue on github IMO,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for a well formated string (your example suggests it) you can use a label argument to the cut function.

```
## create labels from breakpoints
breaks=[0,20,25,30,pd.np.inf]
diff=np.diff(breaks).tolist()

## make tuples of *breaks* and length of intervals
joint = list(zip(breaks,diff))

## format label
s1 = "{left:,.0f} to {right:,.0f}"
labels = [s1.format(left=yr[0], right=yr[0]+yr[1]-1) for yr in joint]
labels

['0 to 19', '20 to 24', '25 to 29', '30 to inf']
```

Then, cut using the `breaks` and `labels`.

```
df['agebin'] = pd.cut(df['agepreg'],breaks, labels=labels, right=False)
```

And summarize:

```
df.groupby('agebin')['agebin'].size()
```

Comment: In your example `labels` results in `[]` which leads to the error `Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges` when running your cut method.

Comment: Really? The label list is one shorter on mine than the breaks list. Or your labels list is empty?

Comment: I am using python 3. Could that make a difference? I am copy and pasting your code into my editor and to the best of my knowledge, I am getting an empty array.

Comment: Ah. I am using 2.7. Maybe the string fomating is different there. Is the `joint` list populated?

Comment: Is there a way to get the count of `joint`? I suspect that string format is probably the same between versions, but zip might require equal length arrays.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute '__len__'`

Comment: `sum(1 for i in joint)` yields 0

Comment: ok. In python 3, zip returns an iterator. Instead of `joint = zip(breaks,diff)
`, try `joint =list(zip(breaks,diff))` and see if that gives you a list of tuples with beginning / end points of each interval.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't the problem. For some reason it is related to the line you just removed `labels = ["{left:,.0f} to {right:,.0f}".format(left=yr[0], right=yr[0]+yr[1]-1) for yr in joint]`. Without this, it works fine!

Comment: but you run it with `joint =list(zip(breaks,diff))`, yes?

Answer (score 2):

You could use iterate over the frame using `iterrows` and then work on categorical value like

```
In [679]: for x, i in agepreg_count.iterrows():
   .....:     print ' to '.join(x[1:-1].split(', ')), i['agepreg']
   .....:
0 to 20 0
20 to 25 43
25 to 30 27
30 to inf 30
```

Comment: Do I have to parse it as a string? Is there not an object/property way of doing this?

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens (unfortunately) I think these are stored as strings.

Comment: @AndyHayden, thanks, I have posted a [follow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189607/python-introspection-how-would-i-verify-that-values-in-a-series-are-strings)

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens Uh, type(x) == str

Comment: Can I do it without iterating over the series?

Comment: I just changed this to an up-vote instead of the selected answer because ako came up with a better solution. Thanks for your help.