# Python: introspection, How would I verify that values in a series are strings?

Tags: python, pandas

Building on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188949/python-how-to-find-properties-of-items-in-a-series/33189068?noredirect=1#comment54184776_33189068), I was told that pd.cut produces strings. For example:

```
agepreg_cuts = pd.cut(df['agepreg'],[0,20,25,30,pd.np.inf], right=False)
agepreg_cuts[0:10]
```

The above code will give me the following values

```
0    [30, inf)
1    [30, inf)
2      [0, 20)
3      [0, 20)
4      [0, 20)
5     [25, 30)
6     [25, 30)
7    [30, inf)
8     [25, 30)
9    [30, inf)
Name: agepreg, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [[0, 20) < [20, 25) < [25, 30) < [30, inf)]
```

I am told that these values (e.g. `[25, 30)`) are strings and therefore I would have to parse it to get the begin and end values. How would I verify that these are indeed strings?

---

For reference, the data I am using comes from the [nsfg](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg.htm). The free book [thinkstats2](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/) has companion code and data on [github](http://github.com/allendowney/thinkstats2).

From the 'code' directory, you can run the following line to load the dataframe.

```
import nsfg
df = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()
df
```

Comment: You could check type(x) in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the `type` function to the Series values:

```
In [11]: agepreg_cuts.apply(type)
Out[11]:
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
5    <class 'str'>
6    <class 'str'>
7    <class 'str'>
8    <class 'str'>
9    <class 'str'>
dtype: object

In [12]: agepreg_cuts.apply(type).value_counts()
Out[12]:
<class 'str'>    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
isinstance(agepreg_cuts, str)
```

Comment: The results are actually key/value pairs (I think), so your answer won't work. I have updated the question description to better reflect the problem.

Comment: Yes, it returns False.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens just create a loop , traverse each elements and check for a string

Comment: I was hoping that there was a better way. :-(